# Functionality of sizeof

Tags: c

Why dose the folowing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    int x;
    long l;
    double d;
    printf("\n%d",sizeof(x+l+d));
    return 0;
}
```

prints on the console 8?
I originaly thought that will convert `x` and `l` to double and display 24.
Why 8?

Comment: Because `sizeof` inspects the type of its argument. `x + l + d` is an expression of type `double`, hence its size is – apparently – 8 bytes. By the way, printing the result of `sizeof` with the `%d` conversion specifier is undefined behavior – the proper format string for `size_t` is `%zu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the number of bytes used to store its argument. In this case its argument is `x+l+d`. `x` is an `int`, `l` a `long`, and `d` a `double`. When you add integer types to `double`s, the result is promoted to form a `double`. So what you have written is the equivalent of `sizeof(double)`. A `double` takes 8 bytes to store, so you are seeing `8` as the result.

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing one argument to sizeof, and that single argument's type is `double`. If you wrote sizeof(x) + sizeof(l) + sizeof(d), that would be something different (although still not 24, because not each argument is `double`).